# Backbone and spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone.js

Hi I am just starting to learn backbone.js and now I am trying to integrate it with spring mvc, I looked everywhere for a simple example using the two to get an idea how it works but all I found was a few complex examples which I tried and failed to understand.Could you please provide me examples and help me do a simple hello world example using Backbonejs and spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can start with Spring Getting Started Guide "[Consuming a RESTful Web Service with Backbone.js](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-backbone/)"

Or go for a full stack like **[RESThub](http://resthub.github.io/)** with the "[Spring Stack tutorial](http://resthub.github.io/docs/spring/tutorial/)".

Answer (score 0):

If you are familliar with the usage of Spring MVC, you can try using the "jackson" extension on your controllers. Jackson has the ability to turn your data requests into replies that are in the form of Data Transfer Objects (specifically JSON).

Since Backbone.js will handle all of your frontend needs, it is alright to use only the Model and Controller parts of the Spring MVC framework. Backbone.js's models will therefore consume your jackson integrated Spring MVC rest service, and can the be rendered in Backbone Views.